# .htaccess How to rewrite img.php?p=$id to img/$id?

Tags: .htaccess

How to rewrite img.php?p=$id to img/$id in .htaccess, where $id is id of the image in database?

I tried this, but I get error - nothing found.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule img/^([0-9_-]+)$ img.php?p=$1
RewriteRule img/^([0-9_-]+)/$ img.php?p=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^img/([0-9_-]+)$ /img.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out.